# How can I pass a function with argument to a component?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-components

I want to pass a function from the parent component to the child component and give it an argument that has also been given from the parent component to the child. (showOrHideSub="item.showOrHideSub(item.id)" ) I have tried different ways and it doesn't work.

This is my html (parent component) in which I want to use the child component tag. vm is the controller of this scope:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in vm.menuItems">
<menu-item-comp id="item.id" showOrHideSub="item.showOrHideSub(item.id)" />
</li>
```

Here is the child component template. itemVm is the controller of this component:

```
<div id="{{itemVm.id}}" ng-mouseover="itemVm.showOrHideSub(itemVm.id)">
<div id="itemVm.subId" class="menuItemImgText">{{ itemVm.label }}</div>
```

Here is the child component js:

```
    module.component('menuItemComp', {
        templateUrl: '/webapp/app/components/menu/menuItemComponent.html',
        bindings: {
            id: '<',
            showOrHideSub: '&',
            label: '<',
            submenuId: '<',
        },
        controllerAs: 'itemVm',
        controller: ['LogService', menuCtrl]
    });

    function menuCtrl($scope, LogService) {

        var itemVm = this;
    }
```

And here is the showOrHideSub() function in the parent controller:

```
    vm.showOrHideSub = function (submenu) {
        console.log(submenu);
        switch (submenu) {
            case 'menuItemDivPositions':
                console.log('position');
                break;
            case 'menuItemDivOther':
                console.log('other');
                break;
        }
    }
```

I know that in directives the way to do it is by object mapping such as showOrHideSub="item.showOrHideSub({item: item.id})" but it doesn't seem to work in component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with components, you have to do it the components way.
It looks like you have a hierarchy of components (child / parent).

Functions and attributes inside the parent can be inherited by children using `require`.

```
require: {
  parent: '^^parentComponent'
}
```

This way, if the parent defines a function `showOrHideSub`, the children can call it directly using `this.parent.showOrHideSub(xxx)`

This is not the only way to solve your issue but this is the *right way*™ for the architecture you chose.

```js
var parentComponent = {
    bindings: {},
    controller: ParentController,
    template: `
      <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.menuItems">
        <child-component item="item"></child-component>
      </li>
    `
};
var childComponent = {
    bindings: {
      item: '<'
    },
    require: {
      parent: '^^parentComponent'
    },
    controller: ChildController,
    template: '<button ng-click="$ctrl.buttonClick($ctrl.item.id);">{{$ctrl.item.name}}</button>'
};
function ParentController() {
  this.menuItems = [{id:1, name:"item1"},{id:2, name:"item2"}];
  this.showOrHideSub = function(param) {
     console.log("parent function called with param: " + param);
  }
}
function ChildController() {
  var vm = this;
  this.buttonClick = function(id) {
    vm.parent.showOrHideSub(id);
  }
}

angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app')
    .component('parentComponent', parentComponent)
    .component('childComponent', childComponent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <parent-component></parent-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 'item' to 'vm' in below code. You are binding the item function '**showOrHideSub(item.id)**' which doesn't exist. Here is the updated code.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in vm.menuItems">
   <menu-item-comp id="item.id" showOrHideSub="vm.showOrHideSub(item.id)" />
</li>
```